# How to combine tables as columns without id or something?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which I receive from function:

```
SELECT val FROM dbo.StringSeparatorParser('1,2,3', ','):

Table
---
1
2
3
```

```
SELECT val FROM dbo.StringSeparatorParser('2,3,4', ',')

Table
--------
2
3
4
```

I need to combine them, or insert into new table like this:

```
Column1       Column2
-----------------
1           2
2           3
3           4
```

How can I do that?:)

Comment: Use subqueries/CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER`. Show us what you've tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Does `dbo.StringSeparatorParser` function return the position of each substring?

Comment: Where did `StringSeparatorParser` come from? What is the DDL of it? A Good splitter gives you the ordinal position of the value.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the value 5 to one of the sets?

Comment: Your sample data is insufficient to tell whether the order of the input values matters. Would the result be different if the first comma-delimited string was `'2,1,3'`? Are the values being sorted before being combined? If the strings have different numbers of values, e.g. `'1,2,4'` and `'1,1,2,3,5'` what should happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a column to join them on.  You can generate one using `row_nmber()`:

```
select i.id, c.capacity
from (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from ids
     ) i join
     (select capacity, row_number() over (order by capacity) as seqnum
      from capacities
     ) c
     on i.seqnum = c.seqnum;
```